# HTML input tag type color, prevent automatic mobile zoom when active

Tags: html, css, input, mobile, colors

I wonder how to prevent the mobile phone, both iOS and Android to prevent automatic zoom when an input tag of type "color" is selected. I have seen a few solutions online but none of them fit my use case. Here is what I have found so far and my comment on them.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0"/>`
This prevents all zoom, even manual zoom on my phone, which is not great.

Adding `style="font-size:16px;` to the input tag.
This doesn't work on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set `font-size` rule when `input` is focused:

```
input[type="color"]:focus {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```